# "sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz " error when trying to install Oracle Java

Tags: java

i recently tried installed java 7 on ubuntu 12.04 and i think i screwed something up

I followed [the instructions given here](http://www.unixmen.com/201204-top-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-2/).

```
First you need to remove openjdk for this run the following command from your terminal

sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
Now you can install Java7 by adding the following repository:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

---

Now everytime i install a new program i get the following error:

```
Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-central (0.6.17ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-eggtrayicon (2.25.3-11) ...
Setting up gmail-notify (1.6.1.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
Error in function:
```

---

However.The program seems to install and work just fine so it doesn't seem to be a problem preventing me from doing anything

So then i reinstalled openjdk by going:

sudo apt-get install openjdk*

But i still get the same error.

going:

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer gives me the same error.

What is going on?

Please let me know if this is clear or not and ill try to explain my issue better

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Run the following commands from a Terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

---

> Information about what PPAs are, as well as tips on recognizing which of them are unsafe, can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out).

---

#### Glossary

> **[Command, command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: the traditional Unix environment , where you type commands to tell the computer what to do.
>
> **[Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: an application that allows you to access the command line. Open it by hitting its keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: YOU DA MAN SirCharlo!!!

Comment: I'm happy it worked :P

Comment: Unable to locate package?

Comment: This no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is quite simple, actually. Please install Synaptic Package Manager in the Ubuntu Software Center, first. After installed, you will need to open it with root privileges:

```
gksu synaptic
```

Or else in Ubuntu 12.04 or later, you can search for synaptic in the Dash and click on the Synaptic icon to open Synaptic. You will be asked to authenticate with your user password in order to open Synaptic.

Search for Oracle-java7-installer, right click on it, and completely remove it. Apply the changes, remove the PPA, and your error messages will be gone.[image]

Comment: No need to install synaptic just for this.  You can use `apt-get remove --purge oracle-java7-installer`, the `--purge` is the equivalent of synaptic's "completely remove" option