# How to remove a half-installed package? (Sun JDK - Java)

Tags: 12.04, apt, java, ppa, dpkg

I've tried installing Sun JDK from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/java`, it failed with the following:

```
Downloading...
--2012-05-05 15:50:09--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 80.239.230.162
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|80.239.230.162|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2012-05-05 15:50:09--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2.17.254.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2.17.254.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-05-05 15:50:09--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|80.239.230.162|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz'

     0K .....                                                 100% 20.5M=0s

2012-05-05 15:50:09 (20.5 MB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
```

So apparently it's trying to fetch a bad URL. I've installed Java manually, but now the package is stuck as a half-installed and every time I `apt-get install` anything, the error appears again.

`apt-get install -f` shows "1 not fully installed or removed." package and fails with the same error. I've tried `dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer`, but it fails as well.

How to remove this half-installed package?

Comment: See answer here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error/352386#352386

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Awww yeahh.. I've been able to finally remove after finding [this post](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/short-tip-remove-packages-on-debian-systems-with-ultimate-force/) the following way: `sudo find /var/lib/dpkg -exec grep -l "oracle-java7-installer" {} \;` showed a bunch of files, I've added `exit 0` to first line by typing `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer.prerm`, saved file and closed gedit.  Finally, after I was back on command line, typed `sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer` and it worked.

Comment: By the way, if you want to fix the half-installed package rather than manually installing Java, the answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-7u3-linux-x64-tar-gz-error-when-trying-to-install-orac) should facilitate that.

Comment: Worked fine! In my case I had to edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer.postinst and add an exit 0 there.

Answer (score 4):

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*

sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*

sudo apt-get update

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I would love to work out how I get to know to look for that first line. It's bugged me for weeks

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Synaptic Package Manager' to remove OR fix broken packages

To download and install 'Synaptic Package Manager' type the following command in the terminal >>

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Comment: Does not work. Marked the package for removal, clicked "apply" - the package is still there. I'm guessing it gets the same error