# Problem by installing Java

Tags: software-center, java, android, dpkg

Yesterday night I was trying to download Java as per instructions given on http://developer.android.com/ .But I messed up somewhere and had to give up the thing. But since morning when ever I try to install or remove some thing I get the following response 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1198084/

Please help fast. I am a newbie in android development and have to submit an app within 5 days from now for a project. And I need my linux machine working fine for that.

Answer (score 2):

A clean install needed. Follow these steps

Download [jdk-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u7-b10/jdk-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz) and put it in your **Desktop** folder.

Open a terminal and type

`sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*`

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java`

`cd ~/Desktop`

`sudo -s cp -r jdk-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/local/java`

`cd /usr/local/java`

`sudo -s chmod a+x jdk-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz`

`sudo -s tar xvzf jdk-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz`

`sudo gedit /etc/profile` then copy and paste [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1198118/) at the bottom of the document

Then run these command to set java as default for your system.....

`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/javac" 1`

`sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/javac`

`. /etc/profile`

Then check your Java version with `java -version`

Comment: I am not able to excecute the first command itself :( If I am tryin g to remove a package why does it show Java stuff here??

Comment: It means Java was not installed correctly. Please follow the rest of procedure.

Comment: even if the first step fails?? and the link dose not give how to download the tar file

Comment: I can excecute this step
'sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java" 1'

It gives this error


update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok. It because we are installing `jdk` not `jre`. let me edit the post....

Answer (score 1):

Ohk so thanks @Kaktarua for your help but I realized my mistake. Yesterday night when I was trying to install Sun JDK - Java I messed up somewhere and so it was only half-installed (ohk I don't know the right term for it.)

So whenever I tried to install or remove something, the apt program tried to install the java thing as well once it had installed the current program.

So I had to remove java stuff from the list of queued downloads. That I did using

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer.prerm*
```

Add  "exit 0" to first line, save file and close gedit. Then type

```
sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer
```

I searched on Ask Ubuntu and came across this answer which proved very helpful:

- [How to remove a half-installed package? (Sun JDK - Java)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132053/how-to-remove-a-half-installed-package-sun-jdk-jav)