# Oracle java -version doesn't work

Tags: java, oracle

I've installed java by following [this instruction](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) and also had installed java 7 from elsewhere but I can't seem to get it to work.. every time I type in java -version via terminal (I am ssh-ing to an ubuntu server) I get this:

```
root@ip-(...):/# java -version
bash: /usr/local/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

This is my Path variable:

```
root@ip-(...):/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/root/bin:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_09/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_09/bin
```

The path variable has two mentions of `jre/bin` but apart from that I don't see anything strange (and this was because I installed it twice? - but either way, it shouldn't matter)

So how do I debug why my `java -version` returns `no such file or directory` error when I can clearly see that the directory does have java in it?

I don't know what other info I need to provide since I am a ubuntu beginner, but please ask if you need anything else.

Comment: Cant be sure but just check it out once http://askubuntu.com/questions/186422/problem-by-installing-java/186638#186638

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think PPAs work any more.

The most popular way NOW is: https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6
NOTE: build .deb from OTN binaries and set up a local repository, install from there.

You can run `update-alternatives --config java` and see installed JDK/JRE and configure.

Comment: hi, ``update-alternatives --config java`` and selecting option 0 fixed it for me, no idea what was wrong but it works now, thanks!