# How to remove error message when installing new softwares

Tags: installation, command-line, software-center, java

First I had installed oracle java via terminal. its get en error. I don't remember the error message. but other java app are working example netbeans, eclipse. The main problem is when i installed any new softwares via terminal or ubuntu software center, first i get this error.

```
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to remove this message and and reinstall java properly. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

**EDIT**
When i trying to remove the Sun Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 7 i got this error message.

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 189962 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing oracle-java7-installer ...
update-alternatives: error: unknown argument `cdrom'
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Downloading...
--2012-05-21 22:54:41--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 222.165.168.249, 222.165.168.202
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|222.165.168.249|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz [following]
--2012-05-21 22:54:42--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 173.222.122.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|173.222.122.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-05-21 22:54:43--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|222.165.168.249|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz'

     0K .....                                                 100%  152K=0.03s

2012-05-21 22:54:43 (152 KB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-7u3-linux-x64-tar-gz-error-when-trying-to-install-orac. If the solution there doesn't work for you, please comment here to indicate it didn't help (but it probably will).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

Answer (score 1):

Running these commands should fix your problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --purge reinstall oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If they do not, then please edit your question to include all the text from the Terminal from when you ran them (as the output would still be diagnostically useful).

Comment: Its not working still i got that error. and I updated the question again.

Comment: @Mifas If you want to continue trying to get the method you're using to work, then please also provide the output of `apt-cache policy oracle-java7-installer` in your question. But you might consider using [this method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) instead.

Comment: @Mifas If the solution at http://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-7u3-linux-x64-tar-gz-error-when-trying-to-install-orac **does** work for you, please comment here and I'll delete this answer (because that would mean this answer is just a less-good version of that answer).

Comment: jeb@AMD-Athlon-II-X3:~$ apt-cache policy oracle-java7-installer
oracle-java7-installer:
  Installed: 7u3-0~eugenesan~precise4
  Candidate: 7u5-0~webupd8~5
  Version table:
     7u5-0~webupd8~5 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7u3-0~eugenesan~precise4 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
jeb@AMD-Athlon-II-X3:~$

Answer (score 1):

The fix is quite simple, actually. Please install Synaptic Package Manager in the Ubuntu Software Center, first. After installed, you will need to open it with root privilages:

```
sudo synaptic
```

Search for Oracle-java7-installer, right click on it, and completely remove it. Apply the changes, remove the PPA, and your error messages will be gone.[image]

Comment: +1 Had `sha256sum mismatch` with `oracle-java8-installer` using synaptic and marking for complete removal then reinstalling worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Synaptic Package Manager is very useful in removing a file which has a dependency issue, and particularly when `sudo apt-get install -f` does not work.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Surely Synaptic would be running the same code to try and remove the broken package.