# Get error on install Java

Tags: apt, java, oracle

I tried install Java 8 for Oracle PPA but get a error. I have viewed [“sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz ” error when trying to install Oracle Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/) and [How to remove error message when installing new softwares](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140312/) these two article and tried to fix it but failed. Can anyone help me with this?

1st Attempt Install Log:

```
sysadmin@VM-ELK-ES:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  binutils gsfonts gsfonts-x11 java-common libfontenc1 libxfont1 x11-common
  xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc default-jre equivs binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk
  ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic
  ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming firefox firefox-2
  iceweasel mozilla-firefox iceape-browser mozilla-browser epiphany-gecko
  epiphany-webkit epiphany-browser galeon midbrowser moblin-web-browser
  xulrunner xulrunner-1.9 konqueror chromium-browser midori google-chrome
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils gsfonts gsfonts-x11 java-common libfontenc1 libxfont1
  oracle-java8-installer x11-common xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,429 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libfontenc1 amd64 1:1.1.2-1 [15.6 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main oracle-java8-installer all 8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0 [22.1 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libxfont1 amd64 1:1.4.7-1ubuntu0.2 [95.0 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main binutils amd64 2.24-5ubuntu3.1 [2,076 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main java-common all 0.51 [130 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main x11-common all 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1 [49.5 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main xfonts-encodings all 1:1.0.4-1ubuntu1 [583 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main xfonts-utils amd64 1:7.7+1 [73.9 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main gsfonts-x11 all 0.22 [9,108 B]
Fetched 6,429 kB in 21s (298 kB/s)                                             
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfontenc1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 58551 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfontenc1_1%3a1.1.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfontenc1:amd64 (1:1.1.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxfont1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxfont1_1%3a1.4.7-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxfont1:amd64 (1:1.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package binutils.
Preparing to unpack .../binutils_2.24-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils (2.24-5ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package java-common.
Preparing to unpack .../java-common_0.51_all.deb ...
Unpacking java-common (0.51) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up binutils (2.24-5ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-installer.
(Reading database ... 58793 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-installer_8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
Unpacking oracle-java8-installer (8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gsfonts.
Preparing to unpack .../gsfonts_1%3a8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gsfonts (1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11-common.
Preparing to unpack .../x11-common_1%3a7.7+1ubuntu8.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11-common (1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xfonts-encodings.
Preparing to unpack .../xfonts-encodings_1%3a1.0.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xfonts-encodings (1:1.0.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xfonts-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../xfonts-utils_1%3a7.7+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xfonts-utils (1:7.7+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gsfonts-x11.
Preparing to unpack .../gsfonts-x11_0.22_all.deb ...
Unpacking gsfonts-x11 (0.22) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libfontenc1:amd64 (1:1.1.2-1) ...
Setting up libxfont1:amd64 (1:1.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up java-common (0.51) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2015-05-25 07:22:54--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 192.168.191.51:3142... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz’

     0K                                                      100% 38.5M=0s

2015-05-25 07:22:55 (38.5 MB/s) - ‘jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz’ saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up gsfonts (1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up x11-common (1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1) ...
 * Setting up X socket directories...                                                                                        [ OK ] 
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up xfonts-encodings (1:1.0.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xfonts-utils (1:7.7+1) ...
Setting up gsfonts-x11 (0.22) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

2nd Attempt:

After following the instruction at [first article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/)

```
sysadmin@VM-ELK-ES:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core
  ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming firefox firefox-2 iceweasel mozilla-firefox iceape-browser
  mozilla-browser epiphany-gecko epiphany-webkit epiphany-browser galeon
  midbrowser moblin-web-browser xulrunner xulrunner-1.9 konqueror
  chromium-browser midori google-chrome
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java8-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/22.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 221 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-installer.
(Reading database ... 59085 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-installer_8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Unpacking oracle-java8-installer (8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2015-05-25 07:31:01--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 192.168.191.51:3142... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 416 Invalid range: 5307-

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

NOTICE: I have use apt-cacher as a apt proxy by following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server)

Comment: Try removing the proxy and making a direct connection.

Comment: Can't you turn off apt-cacher for this update and try to download/install it directly? That would eliminate a possible error cause. And delete the downloaded file, maybe you have to search for it (`jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz`), maybe it gets removed with a simple `sudo apt-get clean`...

Comment: ok, it works. Seems that apt-cacher blocks me to download `jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz`, so sha256sum got error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from OPs question:

> SOLVED: The problem was cause by the apt-cacher, I have opened a [new
>   post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628066/), welcome anyone come and
>   help me to solve the new problem.