# APT-GET did NOT download package correctly via APT-CACHER

Tags: server, apt, apt-cacher

I follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server) to setup the apt-cacher but it did NOT download some files correctly via wget(i think it is). In my [previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628046), I'm going to install Oracle Java 8, and the apt downloaded a html page but not a install package

```
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2015-05-25 07:22:54--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 192.168.191.51:3142... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz’

     0K                                                      100% 38.5M=0s

2015-05-25 07:22:55 (38.5 MB/s) - ‘jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz’ saved [5307/5307]
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

NOTICE: I have change the the `installer_files_regexp` from `[a-z]+\.tar\.gz(?:\.gpg)?` to `[a-z0-9\-]+\.tar\.gz(?:\.gpg)?` otherwise I can't download the file with a file name like `jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate question, because I can download and install Oracle Java when I'm not using apt-cacher as proxy. The problem is on apt-cacher, Java is just an example.