# Auto update not working

Tags: 12.04, updates

When I get new updates, I can't install them. When I try to install I get the following error message.

```
installArchives() failed: Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 191976 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace resolvconf 1.63ubuntu11 (using .../resolvconf_1.63ubuntu14_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement resolvconf ...
Preparing to replace libutouch-geis1 2.2.9-0ubuntu2 (using .../libutouch-geis1_2.2.9-0ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libutouch-geis1 ...
Preparing to replace vino 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 (using .../vino_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement vino ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u3-0~eugenesan~precise4) ...
Downloading...
--2012-05-23 19:40:37--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 223.224.12.144, 223.224.12.146
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|223.224.12.144|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz [following]
--2012-05-23 19:40:38--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 173.223.2.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|173.223.2.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-05-23 19:40:41--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|223.224.12.144|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz'

     0K .....                                                 100%% 52.9K=0.1s

2012-05-23 19:40:41 (52.9 KB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up resolvconf (1.63ubuntu14) ...
Setting up libutouch-geis1 (2.2.9-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up vino (3.4.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for resolvconf ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
Error in function:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-7u3-linux-x64-tar-gz-error-when-trying-to-install-orac.

Comment: I didn't see that one. Looks like a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the packages the oracle-java7-installer downloads. When packages are downloaded, they have whats called a checksum. A checksum is basically a unique string that is created by looking at the contents of the package. This is created when the package is uploaded to the repos, and then your computer creates its own checksum when it downloads the package. Your computer then verifies that your checksum matches the repo checksum and if they are different, it won't install the package.

I am guessing that it is an issue with the repo which would be fixed soon. In the meantime, you can disable updating of that particular package (called pinning or holding), so you can continue to install all of your other updates. The command to do this is:

```
sudo su
echo oracle-java7-installer hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

You should now be able to run updates normally, and updates for oracle-java7-installer will be ignored. When you want to unpin the package and try again at updating it, just simply re-install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

For more information on pinning: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem and I followed the steps from this post and got it to work:

http://rootzwiki.com/topic/23008-howto-install-java-7-on-ubuntu-1204/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.