# Ubuntu 12.10 help configuring Eclipse 4.2.1 for Pydev plugin 32bit resolved

Tags: eclipse

Trying to run 'hello world" py file, So I installed Eclipse and I cant seem to get the py file I select to run. jdk 7 crashed with a SIGBUS error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse goto Help->install new software(popup window will open)->add(popup window will open)->Name(enter 'Pydev' in 'name' box)->Location(enter http://pydev.org/updates) click 'ok'.

In the below box 'select all' -> 'next', accept the terms and conditions and finish.

Eclipse will Install software and ask for certificate confirmation, select and 'OK'

Restart Eclipse and create a project, eclipse will 'auto config' [Auto Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO6Zh.jpg)

That's it.

You are ready to go.!

(I do not have enough reputation to post images, so pasted Links instead)

Comment: Actually I have done that already but the im sure the issue is with java.

Comment: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0xb7754968, pid=2985, tid=3075872448
#
# JRE version: 7.0_15-b20
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux.so.2+0xb968]  _dl_rtld_di_serinfo+0x2e48
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Comment: Are you using 32bit or 64bit Linux? #Looks like you are trying to run 64bit on his 32 bit linux.

Comment: Im running 32 bit. I have removed eclipse and will defer to another editor

Comment: You need to install Sun Java first I think (not entirely sure), unpack it to your /home/{java_folder} somewhere then use `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /home/{java_folder}/bin/java 10`   best try with java6 first, you can always set different alternatives later (`man update alternatives`)

Comment: Have a look at this. Similar errors were reported:
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005164/eclipse-adt-bundle-fatal-error-not-able-to-start

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314312/java-application-crash

3. http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6563308

Hope this might work.

Comment: @ZafrullahSyed I mustve just missed your post... I had a look and its the same error. :D thanks I will look into this. I would prefer to solve this error rather than walk away from it

Comment: bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6563308 the bug is a SIGBUS error in JDK... runs out of temporary space then crashes. it doesnt say how to fix it. the error they have there is slightly different than mine but the same result

Comment: If anyone is interested I found this that helped solve my java woes, plus I learned how to set my su pw! glad this is resolved and now will try eclipse again

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-7u3-linux-x64-tar-gz-error-when-trying-to-install-orac

Answer (score 0):

Further you need to go to Eclipse, make is recognise the Python Interpreter. i.e **Eclipse- Preferences- find Pydev**, expand it---and find Python interpreter, click on it. In the right pane, under Python Interpreters --**click New**, Give a name for your interpreter, then browse to give the directory containing the Python.exe (Windows: Program Files- Python--Python.exe), then confirm for the libraries , then apply. 
Then **click Window menu in Eclipse, Open Perspectives,--other..**--select Pydev and ok.
Then you now create a new Pydev project(File menu), then a new pyDev module as ypur .py script