# How to reinstall Java completely?

Tags: dpkg, java, jdk

I tried to install Java 11 in Ubuntu 18.04, and the first time the installation process crashed. Then I tried to install Java again, but it gave an error like below.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Seems like a problem with sha256sum hash signature, but i don't know how to fix it. May be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/

Comment: It's dosen't work for me.still coming same error.