# Error while upgrading through sudo apt-get upgrade command

Tags: update-manager

Setting up oracle-java11-installer-local (11.0.5-1~linuxuprising0) ...
Before installing this package,
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,

E.g.:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
**Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

Comment: There must be much more output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz " error when trying to install Oracle Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-7u3-linux-x64-tar-gz-error-when-trying-to-install-orac)

Comment: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Comment: Please use search

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask