# How do i delete java 7 runtime?

Tags: java, minecraft

I upgraded to java 7 JDK bur minecraft got a black screen after startup.I found out that java 7 didnt work with linux. when i deleted the JDK, minecraft wouldent even open.every java 7 icon is still there, even though it got erased.
I have openjdk6 on the computer too.

Comment: What procedure did you follow to upgrade/delete the JDK? If you upgraded that means the current stable version of JDK would be JDK 7.

Comment: @edwin i followed a procedure and this was the command sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?? (Because there is the `openjdk`.) You could also read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121226/how-to-completely-remove-a-oracle-jdk-that-didnt-install-properly)

Comment: @edwin im using 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

- $ java -version
  will tell you which version of java is being used. Since the java icon is still there , it might be still present on your system.

Comment: @ Vihaan Verma it just says "The program "java" can be found in the following packages".

Comment: @kid: So it seems the game is not running because you have uninstalled java from your system completely. Since it was running fine with the previous version of java( java 6) , you can open up the software center and install java 6. I think this should fix your problem.

Comment: I have alreadt installed openjdk6 but it seems like the actual version of java 7 from oracle is still on my sytem.

Comment: if java and javac commands dont run on your system, then you dont have them installed. If you are sure that openjdk6 is present on your system please upload the snapshot displaying it